# SQL: Searching for the correct record group

Tags: sql

Lets say that we have a ***Groupings*** table that has 2 columns: ***Group_ID*** and ***Item_ID***. Both are ints. For a simplified example lets imagine that the ***Item_ID*** can be one of only 3 values: {1,2,3}. The ***Group_IDs*** then represent the different groups of permutations of this data. So for example:

```
Group_ID Item_ID
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 1
4 2
5 1
5 3
6 2
6 3
7 1
7 2
7 3
```

What SQL could I write that if I inputted a collection of ***Item_Ids*** it would return the ***Group_ID*** related to that collection?

So for example in the above with an input of (2,3) => 6

***Edit:*** I want to use the solution query on a more complex table, where there are 16 different values for the ***Item_ID***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
select group_id
from table t1
where Item_ID in(2,3)
and exists( select 1 from table t2 where t1.group_id=t2.group_id
                having count(distinct t2.Item_ID)=2 )                 

group by group_id
having count(distinct item_id)=2
```

Comment: @Zaynul This does not give the correct response as it actually returns 6 & 7

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no duplicates, I would simply do:

```
select group_id
from t
group by group_id
having sum(case when Item_ID in (2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) = count(*) and
       count(*) = 2;
```

This seems like the simplest approach.

Comment: This returns 6 & 7, not 6 alone

Comment: @Sperick . . . The answer has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Another Sql to do this

```
SELECT Group_id
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Group_id
HAVING COUNT(Item_ID) = 2
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Item_ID = 2 THEN Item_ID END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Item_ID = 3 THEN Item_ID END) > 0
```